# Force menu choice in R

Tags: r

I have to run a lot of models but not all of these models are installed. R asks me in a menu whether I want to install these. As of right now I have to manually type in "1" which is really annoying because I have to run like 200 models of these on a new rig and the models can take anywhere from 5 minutes to 30 minutes to finish running.

```
> installChoice <- menu(c("yes", "no"))

1: yes
2: no

Selection: 
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection:
```

What line do I add in my .R script such that I can force this Selection to automatically prompt to answer a 1 (i.e. yes/true). The package I'm talking about is Caret btw.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but could you just install all the models you know you'll need ahead of time?

Comment: It's more about unknown dependencies. And they are a whole bunch.

Comment: Install everything in the "suggests" entry of Caret? It's not that many packages. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html